# Variável no EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, ejs, plotly

Bom dia pessoal!

Então, vamos lá: Estou tentando utilizar o Plotly para geração de um gráfico de barras, e o mesmo aceita variáveis.
Tenho uma conexão no NODE.JS com um banco de dados e, o NODE.JS em tese (Após um console.log na rota) está passando para a view qual é o objeto JSON com todos os valores do banco que irei usar. O que eu gostaria de saber é... Como posso utilizar uma variável na view para armazenar apenas os valores numéricos que vão ser usados no gráfico (No X)? Até mesmo porque, se eu tiver um valor ou 20 valores numéricos, deverão ser geradas as linhas correspondentes... Devo por isto dentro de um for? A mesma lógica vou usar com o nome (No Y)...
Rota:

```
    app.get('/barras', function(req,res){
    console.log('Database connection online');
    connection.query('select progresso from barra', function(error,result){
        barras = result;
        console.log(barras);
        res.render('admin/barras',barras);
    });
});
```

View:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  <script>
  var barras = barras;
  console.log(barras);
  var data = [{
      type: 'bar',
      x: [17,20,84],
      y: ['teste1', 'teste2', 'teste3'],
      orientation: 'h'
  }];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

O JSON que é enviado é [RowDataPacket { progresso: 11 },RowDataPacket { progresso: 10}, RowDataPacket { progresso: 20 }]

Comment: Já tentei declarar a var sozinha dentro dos <% %>...

Comment: Não entendi muio bem, mas você quer extrair os valores numéricos da busca? Se for, pode ser forEach ou map.

Comment: Exatamente. O ponto é que consegui extrair, faltava a declaração do recebimento em uma variável. barras = <%= JSON.parse(barras[i].progresso) %>; e a variável no gráfico posteriormente. O ponto agora seria fazer um jeito no qual independente de quantos valores forem retornados, a aplicação consiga gerar o número de barras correspondente.  Com forEach não dá...